Issue with Scrollable Component affecting Parent Div's Scroll Behavior
I'm encountering an issue with a scrollable component (KeyWordScroll) affecting its parent div's scroll behavior in my Next js 14 application. I'm using Tailwind CSS and the Shadcn UI library.
The problem is when the KeyWordScroll component grows in size; it causes the parent div to become scrollable, which is not the desired behavior. I want the KeyWordScroll component to be scrollable within its parent div without affecting the parent's scroll behavior.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
// KeyWordScroll Component
export function KeyWordScroll() {
    return (
        <ScrollArea className="w-full rounded-md border overflow-hidden">
            <div className="flex w-full overflow-x-auto space-x-4 p-4">
                {works.map((artwork) => (
                <figure key={artwork.artist} className="shrink-0">
                    <div className="overflow-hidden rounded-md">
                        <Button>
                            {artwork.artist}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            ))}
            </div>
            <ScrollBar orientation="horizontal" />
        </ScrollArea>
    )
}

Page.tsx
<main className="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-4 p-4 lg:gap-6 lg:p-6">
    <KeyWordScroll />
</main>

Layout.tsx
<main className="grid min-h-screen w-full md:grid-cols-[220px_1fr] lg:grid-cols-[280px_1fr]">
    {/* Sidebar Component */}
    <div className="hidden border-r bg-muted/40 md:block">
        {/* Sidebar content */}
    </div>
    {/* Main content */}
    <div className="flex flex-col">
        <Header />
        {children}
    </div>
</main>

What could be a solution here to ensure that the KeyWordScroll component remains scrollable without affecting the parent div's scroll behavior?
Any workaround or alternative approaches?

